# Filter data in JSON string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a JSON string as pulled from some API

> [{"_id"=>"56aefb3b653762000b400000",
>   "checkout_started_at"=>"2016-02-01T07:32:09.120+01:00",
>   "created_at"=>"2016-02-01T07:29:15.695+01:00", ...}]

I want to filter data in this string based on `created_at`, e.g. letting the user chose a specific date-range and then only show the data from this range.

E.g.

```
@output = my_json.where(created_at: start_date..end_date)
```

My first thought was to somehow transfer the JSON string to `Hashie`, to interact with JSON as the data were objects:

```
my_json = (my_json).map { |hash| Hashie::Mash.new(hash) }
```

but that didn't work out

> undefined method `where' for Array:0x007fd0bdeb84e0

How can I filter out data from a JSON string based on specific criteria or even SQL queries?

Comment: from where we will get the value of `start_date` and `end_date` ?

Comment: that comes through `select_date` form params

Comment: Are those Date object or date in string format ?

Comment: You have Array, so you need to use Array#select method to filter..

Comment: like `my_json.select(|order| order.created_at => start_date..end_date)`?

Comment: `my_json.select { |order| order[[created_at'].between?(start_date, end_date) }` like this. But all the date has to be in `Date` object format.

Answer (score 0):

This simplest possible way would be to use `Enumberable#select` directly on the array of hashes:

```
require 'time'
myjson.select { |o| Time.iso8601(o["created_at"]).between?(start_date, end_date) }
```

If you want a fancy interface surrounding the raw data:

```
require 'time' # not needed in rails 
class Order < Hashie::Mash
  include Hashie::Extensions::Coercion
  coerce_key :created_at, ->(v) do
    return Time.iso8601(v)
  end
end

class OrderCollection
  def initialize(json)
    @storage = json.map { |j| Order.new(j) }
  end

  def between(min, max)
    @storage.select { |t| t.created_at.between?(min, max) }
  end
end

orders = OrderCollection.new(myjson)
orders.between(Time.yesterday, Time.now)
```